# Getting error while copying the file from sharepoint to blob storage in ADF

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I am getting this error ,
"ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Upload file failed at path sapoutput.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=System,"

While copying a file from sharepoint site to blob storage
My web activity to get access token is running fine but there is error in copy activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have required permission and you will get this error.

For granting SharePoint access permission you need to register application

Open SharePoint online site **->** Search application id and fill the empty fields **–>** add domain name and register URL

Please follow this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites) for more information.